# I have 5 buttons I want to change mediaPlayer source fonClick of the buttons how to do that?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I am having an issue with mediaPlayer I want to change(file) mediaplayer=mediaplayer.create(r.folder."file") with onClick of botton and change it again if another button is pressed.
I am having  buttons and i want to assign different sounds to be played on every event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make the MediaPlayer variable global in the activity, and assign it when the onCreate methord fires in your Activity like this

```
Private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    
    //assign the media player
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

Assuming you have your 5 buttons assigned as { button1 button2 button3 button4 and button5 } , add onclick listeners to all of them like this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //change the music
        }
});
```

Now what we want to do is that, everytime you click a button we want to reset the existing MediaPlayer and then assign a new file to it, and then play that file.

So in the onClick event of each listener you need to run the code

```
mediaPlayer.reset();

try {
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0....path to yor file");
      mediaPlayer.prepare();
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
catch (Exception ex){
    //we have an exception
};
```

The onClick listeners for each button should now look like this

```
//button1
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //change the music
            mediaPlayer.reset();

            try {
                  mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0....path to yor file");
                  mediaPlayer.prepare();
                  mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                //we have an exception
                };



//button 2
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //change the music
            mediaPlayer.reset();

            try {
                  mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0....path to yor file");
                  mediaPlayer.prepare();
                  mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                //we have an exception
                };

        }
});


        }
});


//Button 3 , 4 and 5
```

Answer (score 0):

use switch statement and based on the id of the button create mediafile with different source